# Hydrogen wave function and angular momentum operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, eigenvalue, hydrogen

I'm working my way through an old exam assignment for my Introduction to Quantum mechanics and a few (parts of) questions have me a little confused.

The assignment is about the hydrogen atom and its stationary states, denoted $|nlm\rangle$ as usually, and with the usual angular momentum operators:

\begin{align}
L^2 |nlm\rangle & = l(l+1)\hbar^2|nlm\rangle \\
L_z |nlm\rangle & = m\hbar|nlm\rangle \\
L_+ & = L_x + iL_y \\
L_- & = L_x - iL_y \\
\end{align}

And a wavefunction given by $|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|210\rangle+|211\rangle)$.

**First Question** Show that $|\psi\rangle$ is an energy eigenstate, and calculate the energy. Is $|\psi\rangle$ an eigenstate for $L^2$?

For the first part of this, showing that $|\psi\rangle$ is an energy eigenstate I have to show that $H|\psi\rangle=E|\psi\rangle$ - i.e. $|\psi\rangle$ is an eigenfunction of H, with eigenvalue E.
To go about this, I would simply calculate $H|\psi\rangle$, but I feel that I'm missing something here.

Should I simply look up the $|210\rangle$ and $|211\rangle$ waves in a table, and calculate the product with the hydrogen Hamiltonian $H= \frac{p^2}{2m}-\frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r}$? It seems very "brute force", am I missing something clever about rewriting $H$ in terms of the angular operators? I scoured my book for information, but couldn't seem to find any tricks of the sort.

$|\psi\rangle$ is an eigenstate for $L^2$ with eigenvalue l(l+1)\hbar^2... Correct?

**Second Question** Determine the expectation value of $L_z$ (in state $|\psi\rangle$). Account for the fact that the standard error of $L_x$ and $L_y$ must be $\sigma_{L(x)} \sigma_{L(y)} \leq \frac{\hbar^2}{4}$

I got the expectation value as $\langle \psi |L_z|\psi \rangle = \frac{1}{2}\langle 210 + 211 |L_z|210 + 211 \rangle=m\hbar$

To get the inequality, I used the generalized uncertainty principle $\sigma^2_A \sigma^2_B \leq \big( \frac{1}{2i}\langle[A,B]\rangle\big)^2$

However this gave me $\sigma^2_{L_x} \sigma^2_{L_y}=\frac{\hbar^2}{4}\langle L_z\rangle^2$.
But I found $\langle L_z\rangle=m\hbar$, which would imply

$$\sigma_{L_x} \sigma_{L_y}=\sqrt{\frac{\hbar^2}{4}m^2\hbar^2}=\frac{\hbar^2m}{2}$$

So clearly I went awry, but I have trouble seeing where.

**Third Question** Expectation values of $L_+|\psi\rangle$ and $L_-|\psi\rangle$

Again, I think there should be some smart way to rewrite these as lower/raising operations, like $L^2$ and $L_z$ in the beginning, but I don't see how they relate to $L_+$ and $L_-$. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You've probably learned that the hydrogen energy eigenvalues depend only on $n$, not on $l$ or $m$.
   Your two states have the same $n$, so they have the same energy. 
   You should find it easy to prove that a linear combination of eigenstates having the same eigenvalue is itself an eigenstate (with that same eigenvalue). That's all you need to establish that $|\psi\rangle$ is an eigenstate of both energy and $L^2$
2. Double-check your calculation for $\langle \psi |L_z|\psi \rangle$. (It can't be right, because you can't end up with an $m$ on the right-hand side; you should have plugged-in specific values for $m$ during the calculation).
3. You should have learned formulae for $L_+$ and $L_-$. They just change the $m$ value of a state (and change its norm), leaving you with a few simple inner products to evaluate and sum.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Although, how does the energy depend on *l*? Is it not strictly dependent on *n*?

Comment: You are right. I fixed the text.

Comment: @Woodenplanck That depends on what level of theory you're working in. For the basic electrostatic hamiltonian, yes, the energy is independent of $\ell$. However, the real levels include relativistic corrections (known as fine structure, at about the 6th significant figure or so, though that doesn't mean it is unimportant) which do lift this degeneracy.